# How to get driving directions within my app iOS6

Tags: ios6, maps, mkmapview, mapkit, apple-maps

I am using Apple Map's in my app and on my view i want to show the driving direction from the user location to the current location that i have on the view, now i just want all this inside my app only i.e i can show the driving direction's on the mapview, I have tried using the apple map application but after i make call to it from my application it takes me to apple's map application where i get the driving direction's but i can not return back into my application so i am thinking that i can do something in my application itself so that i can get the driving directions on my current view itself ..

```
NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude,mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

this code takes me to the apple's map app from  my native app but i can't return directly back to my app.is there a possible solution so that i can move back to my APP AFTER GETTING THE DRIVING DIRECTIONS ?? (webview didnot work for me.can i add a back button on apple's app or what ).Please help.... Thanks a lot !!

Or Please can any one suggest me a better code for implementing so that i can do all of that in my application only ?

**I want an in-app map depicting the navigation routes and driving directions...**

Comment: Do you mean ios4 (which you've tagged) or iOS6 (which you've asked)?

Comment: @Craig: sorry it ws a typo error from my side while tagging ..

Comment: Yeah I figured iOS6 was a bit more likely. In that case you have to be careful about using Google's data on non-Google maps. It's against their TOS and though I don't know if or how they enforce it, it is probably better to avoid pissing them off.

Comment: @Craig: ya i will try to avoid using it.do you have any links for then it would be much helpful..thxs for the help anyhow.cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way to achieve the directions,

I have made a sample for you which covers all the iOS versions, New Google Maps and the iOS 6 tom tom maps as well.

Here it is:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending){
        //6.0 or above
        NSString *Destinationlatlong =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",your.latitude,your.longitude];

        NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",[AppDelegate zDelegate].location.coordinate.latitude,[AppDelegate zDelegate].location.coordinate.longitude, Destinationlatlong];
        addr=[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL* url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:addr]autorelease];
        //    NSLog(@"url %@",url);
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }else{
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coords =
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([your.latitude doubleValue],[your.longitude doubleValue]);
            MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                                      initWithCoordinate:coords addressDictionary:nil];


            MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

            [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
        }
    }else{
        NSString *Destinationlatlong =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",your.latitude,your.longitude];
        NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@",Destinationlatlong];
        addr=[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL* url = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:addr]autorelease];
        //    NSLog(@"url %@",url);
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alert=[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Device does not support this functionality" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil]autorelease] ;
            [alert show];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thxs a lot...@sree charan it worked for me with a little change.Thxs !!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. In short, get driving instruction from google api in json, parse it, and display it on your own map using `MKPolyline`
http://iosguy.com/2012/05/22/tracing-routes-with-mapkit/

Comment: If the niks2000 really means iOS6 then using Google's driving directions on Apple's maps is not a (legal) option.

Comment: i am working with apple's map only and not with google's .if you have any links for that then it would be much helpful..thxs for the help anyhow.cheers!!